# How to sum many keys in a MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection where the documents are of the form:

```
{
    year: 1900,
    alabama: 145,
    arkansas: 103,
    // ... for all 50 US states
}
```

I would like a query that gives the sum over the collection for each state. So a result might look like:

```
{
    alabama: 1360492,
    arkansas: 598023,
    // ... and so on
}
```

The best I've been able to come up with is an aggregate query with 50 terms:

```
db.sample.aggregate({$group: {
    _id: "",
    alabama: {$sum: "$alabama"},
    arkansas: {$sum: "$arkansas"},
    // ... and so on
}});
```

Is there some way to construct the query that allows me to just provide an array of field names that need to be summed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way of doing it using the aggregation framework, but using mapreduce, it's fairly straight forward;

```js
> db.test.insert({ year: 1900, alabama: 145, arkansas: 103 })

> db.test.insert({ year: 1901, alabama: 100, arkansas: 77  })

// Map function, emits the state name and the value for each entry
> var m = function () { 
                        for(var key in this) {
                          if(this.hasOwnProperty(key) && 
                             key != 'year' && key!='_id')
                            emit(key, this[key])
                        }
                      }

// Reduce function, just sums up the score per state
> var r = function (state, score) { return Array.sum(score); }

// Run mapreduce with map function m, reduce function r, and output inline
> db.test.mapReduce(m, r, {out:{inline:1}})

{
"results" : [
    {
        "_id" : "alabama",
        "value" : 245
    },
    {
        "_id" : "arkansas",
        "value" : 180
    }
]
}
```

EDIT: To be able to use the aggregation framework, I can't see a way without changing the data model slightly to be able to access the state as a key;

```
> db.test2.insert({ year: 1900, data:[{k:"alabama", v:145}, 
                                      {k:"arkansas", v:103}] } )

> db.test2.insert({ year: 1901, data:[{k:"alabama", v:100}, 
                                      {k:"arkansas", v:77}] } )

// Unwind data, and group it back together by key while summing the values;
> db.test2.aggregate({$unwind:"$data"},
                     {$group:{_id:"$data.k",total:{$sum: "$data.v"}}})

{ "_id" : "arkansas", "total" : 180 }
{ "_id" : "alabama", "total" : 245 }
```

Comment: Do you have any intuition on how this would compare, performance-wise, with the aggregation framework?

Comment: @TomPanning Aggregation framework is usually faster if you can write an equivalent query, however in this case I don't know of a way of doing it with the existing data model.

Comment: @TomPanning Added a way to use aggregation if changing the data model slightly.